# Let visitors show/hide a type of content

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have three different levels on articles, Level1, level2 and level3. 
In the main section of my homepage, I show all three types of articles, but I want the user to have the option to hide/remove Level3-articles.

The Levels are saved in the database as a meta_value. 
Each post got its level as a class; 
`<article class="news-entry Level3">`

So, to the question: 
How can I let visitors toogle to show/hide the Level3-articles? Preferabbly without reloading the page. Perhaps a simple `display:none`, but I do not know how to make this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is your friend! More specifically jQuery is your friend.

You can us [wp enqueue script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and do something like this:

Add this to your themes functions.php

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');            
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method'); //
?>
```

Then either in your header or by writing a custom .js file then enquiring it use the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.hide_level3_button').click(function(){
          $('.Level3').toggle();
         return false;
   });
});
```

Then just give your toggle button a class of `hide_level3_button` and you're good to go.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/nzE7F/

**UPDATE:** You can also use `fadeToggle()` to mak them fad out which may look better http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/nzE7F/1/

**EDIT**
To add make it work on page load I would add the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and change the javascript to this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($.cookie("hide_level3") == "true") { //check for cookie
        $('.Level3').hide(); //hide the level
    }

    $('.hide_level3_button').click(function() {
        $('.Level3').fadeToggle(); //toggle level
        $.cookie('hide_level3', 'true'); //set the cookie
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/nzE7F/3/

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! :) 
Always forgetting the easiest solution..

Comment: Now, just a follow-up question. How much work would it be to add this to a session? So that the user don't have to click it again on every pageload?

Comment: It works for hiding Level3 and cookie. But if I hide, and show and then reload, it hides Level3.

Comment: Just unset it if they click the link again: http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/nzE7F/6/